# How do you install chrome for cypress in CI

Tags: jenkins, cypress

I have written some cypress tests which I am running on CI using Electron browser. I would like to use chrome browser for running these tests in Jenkins instead. Below is how I cypress is set up to run in Jenkins.

```
            stage("Setup Cypress") {
                echo "SETUP CYPRESS"
                sh "curl --fail https://chromium-blinger.cf.berw-agb-01.cloud.uk.aeee/cypress-4.2.0-linux64.zip > cypress.zip"
                sh "CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=${workspacePath}/${env.repositoryFolder}/cypress.zip npm install cypress && npm run cypress:verify"
            }
```

`CYPRESS_BASE_URL=$ABGENV CYPRESS_ENV=development cypress run --browser chrome **/*.features`

Error I am getting in console is below:

```
Can't run because you've entered an invalid browser name.

Browser: 'chrome' was not found on your system.

Available browsers found are: electron
```

Answer (score 0):

When running in CI , i always prefer to use docker image. That has resolved my issues with regards to browser.

agent {
docker {
image 'cypress/base:10'
}
}

Comment: Hi ! You should consider to remove this answer and post it as a comment under the question instead

Comment: It's not an answer

Comment: @Julien Now i made it sound like an answer, that qualifies i hope.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Cypress docker image directly in a .yml file like:

```
image: cypress/browsers:node16.14.0-slim-chrome99-ff97
```

For more options you can check here https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-docker-images/blob/master/browsers/README.md